# fail to work on the error handling in rust axum

Tags: rust, error-handling, rust-axum

I am starting a simple rust test with axum and mongodb.

Here is the main code

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Post {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub content: String,
    pub title: String,
}

#[async_trait]
impl Schema for Post {
    fn new(payload: Value) -> Result<Self> {
        serde_json::from_str(&payload.to_string())
    }
    fn name() -> String {
        "posts".to_string()
    }
}
```

then I added some error handling with thiserror

```
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum AppError {

  #[error("{0}")]
  Mongo(#[from] MongoError)
  ....
}

impl AppError {
  fn get_codes(&self) -> (StatusCode, u16) {
    match *self {
       AppError::Mongo(_) => (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 5003),
  }
}

impl IntoResponse for AppError {
  fn into_response(self) -> Response {
    let (status_code, code) = self.get_codes();
    let message = self.to_string();
    let body = Json(json!({ "code": code, "message": message }));

    (status_code, body).into_response()
  }
}
```

at last the routing logic

```
Router::new().route("/",post(generic_controller::create::<Post>))


pub trait Bounds: Schema + Serialize + Sync + Send + Unpin + DeserializeOwned {}
impl<T> Bounds for T where T: Schema + Serialize + Sync + Send + Unpin + DeserializeOwned {}

pub async fn create<T: Bounds>(
    State(db): State<Arc<Database>>,
    Json(mut payload): Json<Value>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {

    let collection = db.collection::<T>(&T::name());
        let object = .....; 
        match collection.insert_one(object, None).await {
            Ok(o) => (StatusCode::OK, Json(json!({ "result": o }))),
            Err(e) =>  {
                (
                    StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                    Json(json!({"error": e.to_string()})),
                )
            }
        }
}
```

The code above is compiling well, however I want to replace tuple `(http::StatusCode, axum::Json<serde_json::Value>)` with error handling.

replace the code

```
        match collection.insert_one(object, None).await {
            Ok(o) => (StatusCode::OK, Json(json!({ "result": o }))),
            Err(e) =>  {
                (
                    StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                    Json(json!({"error": e.to_string()})),
                )
            }
        }
```

to

```
        match collection.insert_one(object, None).await {
            Ok(o) => (StatusCode::OK, Json(json!({ "result": o }))),
            Err(e) =>  {
                Err(AppError::Mongo)
            }
        }
```

the error message is

```
Err(AppError::Mongo)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `(StatusCode, Json<Value>)`, found `Result<_, fn(Error) -> ... {AppError::Mongo}>`
   |
   = note: expected tuple `(http::StatusCode, axum::Json<serde_json::Value>)`
               found enum `Result<_, fn(mongodb::error::Error) -> AppError {AppError::Mongo}>`
```

how would I deal with this situation